# Right (and rapid) parameters checking in Java Backend

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, error-handling, ejb

I'm developing a CRUD application using Mybatis in conjunction with EJB 3.1. Those EJBs are invoked by a JAX-RS Web Service.

In the JAX I (obviously) have to check for parameters rightness before invoking the EJBs.

I'm doing something like:

```
int codiCli = req.getParameter("codiCli") != null ? new Integer(
    req.getParameter("codiCli")).intValue() : 0;
int codiIndirizzo = req.getParameter("codiIndirizzo") != null ? new Integer(
    req.getParameter("codiIndirizzo")).intValue() : 0;
String indirizzo1 = req.getParameter("indirizzo1") != null ? req.getParameter("indirizzo1") : "";
if (codiCli <= 0 || !isValid(indirizzo1) || !isValid(localita) ) {
    response = this.createJsonErrorResp("updateIndirizzo", 1, 1002, "Parameters error").toString();
} else {
    try {
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        Object serviceObj = initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/MngClientiDAOService");
        MngClientiDAOServiceRemote service = (MngClientiDAOServiceRemote) javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject
                                .narrow((org.omg.CORBA.Object) serviceObj, MngClientiDAOServiceRemote.class);
        // ...
       }
     //... 
}
```

Is there a better and possibly rapid way of doing all those controls? Maybe is there a Java library or a right pattern to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use Bean Validation to perform validation of parameters. See:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html

If you are using JAX-RS Web Service, you can validate your request parameters by putting them in a bean - like `User` bean in the example below:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/xml")
public void registerUser(@Valid User user) {
    ...
}
```

More examples here: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html#d0e13587

You can also use custom validators if you have more complex cases - see examples implementing `ConstraintValidator` interface.